# How to delete a row based on a condition from a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

From the following array :

```
test = np.array([[1,2,'a'],[4,5,6],[7,'a',9],[10,11,12]])
```

How can I delete the rows that contain 'a' ?
Expected result :

```
array([[ 4,  5,  6],
   [10, 11, 12]])
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note, `numpy` supports vectorized comparisons:

```
>>> test
array([[1, 2, 'a'],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 'a', 9],
       [10, 11, 12]], dtype=object)
>>> test == 'a'
array([[False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Now, you want the *rows* where *all* are not equalt to `'a'`:

```
>>> (test != 'a').all(axis=1)
array([False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

So, simply select the rows with the mask:

```
>>> row_mask = (test != 'a').all(axis=1)
>>> test[row_mask,:]
array([[4, 5, 6],
       [10, 11, 12]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I was trying to find a solution with the np.where function but I did not. Thanks again.

Comment: @GF you could use `np.where`, but I think the solution would be less clean, unless you were looking specifically for the values *where* something was whatever. The problem when you want only the rows or columns is that you have to do an additional step to find unique indices...

Answer (score 3):

Also, like this maybe? (Inspired from one of my [another answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47808028/2956066) )

```
In [100]: mask = ~(test == 'a')

In [101]: mask
Out[101]: 
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [102]: test[np.all(mask, axis=1), :]
Out[102]: 
array([['4', '5', '6'],
       ['10', '11', '12']],
      dtype='<U21')
```

But, please note that here we're *not* *deleting* any rows from the original array. We're just slicing out the rows which doesn't have the alphabet `a`.

Comment: Nice too. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

To sum up, there are a few possible ways such as :

```
test[np.all(test != 'a', axis=1), :]
```

Or

```
test[(test != 'a').all(axis=1)]
```